Cannot resolve symbol mlkit error in Android Studio
By adding the Following  into the build.gradle file :
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-face-detection:16.5.0'
The error below is occurring

Cannot resolve symbol 'mlkit'

enter image description here

Your project setup/dependencies/classpath is not right.
